# Angular/webpack: after build constructor.name become "R" instead of class name

Tags: angular, webpack

In Angular/webpack after the build the constructor.name become "R" instead of class name, eg:

```
export class Foo {
    constructor() {
        console.log(this.constructor.name);
    }
}
```

In developing is

```
Foo
```

In production is:

```
R
```

this happen because Angular minify the code...

Anyway to preserve original constructor name?

Answer (score 0):

You can eject your application by using ng eject --prod and use custom webpack  uglify configurations ("mangle": false)